# What is the difference/relation between /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log?

Tags: apt, package-management, log

About `apt` in the `/var/log/apt` directory appears mostly the `history.log` and `term.log` files and their "variations" (old versions) such as:

- `history.log.1.gz` ... `history.log.11.gz`
- `term.log.1.gz` ... `term.log.11.gz`

**Question**

- What is the difference/relation between `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`?

I saw the content of each one and they are similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`history.log` shows a terse list of what package actions occurred. This is useful to know what happened when, but lacks troubleshooting detail. The predictable format makes machine-reading the file easy.

`term.log` records all the terminal output. This is particularly useful for troubleshooting. It's meant to be human-readable, but includes a lot of extra detail that is unnecessary when nothing is wrong.

There is a lot the same information in both -- the difference is in the kind of query you want: "*What happened during week X?*" vs. "*Why did ABC fail?*"